# R Arima method blocks when adding seasonality

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to build a seasonal arima model using **R** on 5-minutes frequency traffic data. I am using the method **Arima** from package **forecast**.

I have no problem in computing the model without the seasonal component. Instead when I add it to the model, R blocks immediately (and I am forced to reboot).

I initially thought the data-set was too big to handle (it is made of 30k entries), so I tried using a small portion, but this does not seem to be the case, since the issue is exactly the same also with only 600 entries.

That's the code:

```
library(forecast)
timeSeries = ts(scan("input_600.csv"))
model = Arima(timeSeries, order=c(1,1,1), seasonal = list(order=c(1,1,1),period=288))
summary(model)
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**

I got a pc with 16GB of RAM, and I tried computing the model. I can confirm it was a memory issue, since the R process took almost 13GB. However I am still not able to go through it, since I get this new error:

```
Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE, : initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

Still, I will be grateful to anyone who can give me useful suggestions.

Comment: Your period =288 setting is probably too high for the memory. Try to set it lower just for idenityfing the problem. Also see here   http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/

Comment: You're right. With lower periods the issue disappears. I will look at the Fourier series approach mentioned in the link. Thank you

Comment: @HOSS_JFL Just updated the question, you were right it was a memory issue. I found your link very useful, but I would still prefer the classic seasonal arima model if I can manage to compute it.